# Linked list overwrites the previous value

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to create a linked list with classes. I have two classes, one LinkedList and another LinkedNode. My problem is that my function InsertAtEnd always delete the current node. So when I want to print my linked list, I can't see anything.
I know thanks to debugger that in the function InsertAtEnd, we don't enter in the while loop, this is the problem. But after several attemps I can't resolve my problem.

This is my code:

```
void LinkedList::InsertAtend(int data)
{
    LinkedNode* node = new LinkedNode();
    node->setData(data); node->setNext(nullptr);

    LinkedNode* tmp = _header;
    if (tmp != NULL)
    {   
        while (tmp->getNext() != nullptr)
        {
            tmp = tmp->getNext();
        }
        tmp->setData(data);
        tmp->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        _header = node;
    }
}
```

My class LinkedNode:

```
class LinkedNode
{
public:
    LinkedNode();
    ~LinkedNode();
    void setData(int data);
    void setNext(LinkedNode* next);

    int getData() const;
    LinkedNode* getNext() const;

private:
    int _data;
    LinkedNode* _next;
};
```

My class LinkedList:
    #pragma once
    #include 
    #include "LinkedNode.h"
    using namespace std;

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void PrintList();
    void InsertAtend(int data);
    void PrintList() const;

private:
    LinkedNode* _header;
};
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp` is the last Node, so if you don't want to delete it you shouldn't write value `data` in it. You should link it with the new Node, which you named `node`.

Instead of

```
tmp->setData(data);
tmp->setNext(nullptr);
```

You should write

```
tmp->setNext(node)
```

Answer (score 2):

`tmp->setData(data);`
Your tmp is not the node that you're trying to add, but the last in your list.

Comment: What ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: node = your new node to add;  so why are you changing data on any other node?

Comment: What can I do tmp = node ?

Comment: No, tmp = node will replace the existing last node. But you want to append the new node after the last node instead.

Comment: the lines `tmp->setData(data);` and `tmp->setNext(nullptr);` are wrong.  you want to just delete the first - completely, and change the 2nd to be `tmp->setNext(node)`

Comment: You may wish to consider having a pointer to the end so that you don't have to iterate over all your members every time you want to add one.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop, the `tmp` is the last node in the current list. As you want to add the new `node` after the last node, you need to

```
tmp->setNext(node);
```

to append it (and not set the data as the data are already set to the new `node`).

Also note that you actually do not need to iterate through the entire list at all, if you keep another member variable to the current end of the list (`_tail`). Then you can access it directly and simply append and update.